# Gtkbuilder error

Tags: gtk

I have installed GTK+- 2.10.14 with directFB backend for my powerpc target board, i could able to run the example application in my target board and see the gui comes up in target LCD.with that i started creating GUI using glade but while working on Glade to create my own GUI i found that glade required gtkbuildet to compile a .glade file. the gtkbuilder is available from version GTK+-2.12.0, so installed again the GTK+-2.12.0 and fallowed procedure say in [this tutorial](http://www.micahcarrick.com/gtk-glade-tutorial-part-1.html#Introduction_to_Glade3).

My program as follows:

```
#include<gtk/gtk.h>

int
main( int    argc,char **argv )
{

GtkBuilder *builder;
GtkWidget  *window;
GError     *error = NULL;

/* Init GTK+ */
gtk_init( &argc, &argv );

/* Create new GtkBuilder object */
builder = gtk_builder_new();
/* Load UI from file. If error occurs, report it and quit application.
*      * Replace "tut.glade" with your saved project. */
if( ! gtk_builder_add_from_file( builder, "graph.glade", &error ) )
    {
        g_warning( "%s", error->message );
        g_free( error );
        return( 1 );
    }

/* Get main window pointer from UI */
window = GTK_WIDGET( gtk_builder_get_object( builder, "window1" ) );

/* Connect signals */
gtk_builder_connect_signals( builder, NULL );

/* Destroy builder, since we don't need it anymore */
g_object_unref( G_OBJECT( builder ) );

/* Show window. All other widgets are automatically shown by GtkBuilder */
gtk_widget_show( window );

/* Start main loop */
gtk_main();

return( 0 );
}
```

Now when I compile the above program I struck up with as error as below:

```
powerpc-linux-gnu-gcc progressbar.c -o progressbar -pthread -I/opt/gtkdfb/usr/local/include/glib-2.0 -I/opt/gtkdfb/usr/local/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/opt/gtkdfb/usr/local/include/pango-1.0 -I/opt/gtkdfb/usr/local/include/cairo -I/opt/gtkdfb/usr/local/include -I/opt/gtkdfb/usr/local/freetype2 -I/opt/gtkdfb/usr/local/libpng12 -I/opt/gtkdfb/usr/local/includegtk-2.0 -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/opt/gtkdfb/usr/include/directfb -L/opt/gtkdfb/usr/local/lib  -ldirectfb -lfusion -ldirect -lpthread -ldl -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lcairo -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lxml2 -lpng12 -lgthread-2.0 -lgtk-directfb-2.0 -lffi -lz -lm `pkg-config gtk+-2.0 --cflags --libs`

/tmp/ccZ9fkFp.o: In function `main':

progressbar.c:(.text+0x3c): undefined reference to `gtk_builder_new'

progressbar.c:(.text+0x58): undefined reference to `gtk_builder_add_from_file'

progressbar.c:(.text+0xb0): undefined reference to `gtk_builder_get_object'

progressbar.c:(.text+0xd8): undefined reference to `gtk_builder_connect_signals'

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

make: *** [helloworld] Error 1
```

Please help me to come out of this error.

Comment: Are you sure that you program is linking to the new version of Gtk? Try a simple program which prints out the gtk version to check the same, or if `ldd` like tool is available then you can check the shared objects your executable depends on and see if it is actually linking with the newer gtk libraries

Answer (score 0):

When there was no `GtkBuilder`, [libglade](http://developer.gnome.org/libglade/) was used instead. You must use a glade version that supports both GTK+2 and libglade (the [3.8 branch](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/glade3/3.8/) fits the bill).

Do not try to use the directFB back-end on newer GTK+: it was actively maintained by a developer of the Debian installer but it has been abandoned since a long time.

Comment: GTK 2.12 supports GtkBuilder, so he just needs a Glade version that handles GtkBuilder. Libglade is irrelevant to him.

Comment: DirectFB support was broken in GTK 2.14 (http://www.mail-archive.com/directfb-dev@directfb.org/msg08001.html) while it was actively maintained up to at least GTK 2.10.13 (http://directfb.org/wiki/index.php/Projects:GTK_on_DirectFB). I still consider GTK+ 2.10 and libglade a saner choice.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `pkg-config` is still pointing to the old 2.10 version. I also don't understand why you have `pkg-config gtk+-2.0 --cflags --libs` **and** also provide all the GCC command line arguments. That is supposed to be the job of `pkg-config`.